# Projection onto set $\mathcal{C} = \left\{ \mathbf{x}: \left| \mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{x} \right| \leq \gamma \right\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-optimization, projection

I am seeking a projection onto the set defined by

$$\mathcal{C} = \left\{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^m : \left| \mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{x} \right| \leq \gamma \right\}$$

where $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{C}^m$ is a given complex-valued weight vector of length $m$ and $\gamma$ is some given threshold.

On the other hand, if $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ are real-valued vectors, then I can find a projection onto the half-space, e.g. in [1], i.e.,

$$\widetilde{\mathcal{C}} = \left\{ \mathbf{y}:  \mathbf{b}^{T} \mathbf{y} \leq \gamma \right\}$$

as

\begin{align*}
 P_{\widetilde{\mathcal{C}}}\left(\mathbf{y}\right) =
 \left\{ 
   \begin{matrix}
    \mathbf{y} + \frac{\left(\gamma - \mathbf{b}^{T} \mathbf{y}\right)}{\left\|\mathbf{b}\right\|_2^2} \mathbf{b},  &  \text { if }  \mathbf{b}^{T} \mathbf{y} > \gamma; \\
    \mathbf{y},  &  \text { if }  \mathbf{b}^{T} \mathbf{y} \leq \gamma.    
  \end{matrix} 
 \right.
\end{align*}

So, do you think there exist a projection operator for this case $\mathcal{C} = \left\{ \mathbf{x}: \left| \mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{x} \right| \leq \gamma \right\}$? If yes, I would highly appreciate your help and pointers.

Many thanks in advance

[1] N. Parikh, S. Boyd, [Proximal algorithms](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/prox_algs.html), Foundations and Trends in Optimization, volume 1, number 3, pages 123-231, 2013.

Comment: There is something I don't understand here... $\mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{x}$ is a complex, not a real. So how can you speak of an inequality like $\mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{x} \leq \gamma$?

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing assumption. Now I have edited and added that if vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ were real-valued, and without any absolute functionality, then the projection can easily be found in the ref. [1] atleast

Comment: The projection always exists, because $C$ is closed and convex. However, the results you mention in the real case, don't carry over to the complex case, because $C$ is now a conic (defined by a **quadratic** inequality, not half-spaces)...

Comment: thank you for your comment "dohmatob". Do you think there is some clever way to compute the projection in complex-valued case? Example exploiting some proximal operator somehow!? Please suggest. Merci d'avance!

Comment: Will you by satisfied by $ {\left\| {a}^{T} x \right\|}_{2}^{2} \leq \gamma $?

Comment: It is the same thing to me. I don't know what the norm 2 of a scalar means? also squaring the $\gamma^2$!?

Comment: Do you actually mean Transpose ($ {a}^{T} x $) or Hermite Conjugate ($ {a}^{H} x $)?

Comment: I actually mean Transpose, i.e., $z = \mathbf{a}^{\rm T}\mathbf{x}$ such that $z \in \mathbb{C}$.